# how can i fetch mac address of a client machine in django

Tags: django, mac-address

My website is having two type of users
1 : Players
2 : Admin users
I want to store mac address of client machine from which player signup/signin into website.i want to block games if there is two games running from one machine or two player session active at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive there is no way to get mac address in Django. All you can get is HTTP headers in `request` variable.
But still you can get MAC by any other method (via Java applet or ActiveX) and pass it Django by GET or POST request.