# How to get the MAC address of client

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, afnetworking, arp

> On my website I am selling Course materials and user have to pay for that and I want to get the MAC ID of user who purchase my courses so that they cannot use it on other devices. Is that Feasible to code in **Python/Django** ?
>   My approach

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
print mac
```

> The above code gives the MAC ID but this is my server's MAC ID . Is there any possible solution for that then please share.
>   **Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i fetch mac address of a client machine in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654159/how-can-i-fetch-mac-address-of-a-client-machine-in-django)

Comment: Of course not possible.

Answer (score 2):

MAC address isn't preserved during packet transferring. MAC address is used for routing in L2 network segment (aka subnet), which is pretty small: Local Area Network may include several such segments. For packet passing through multiple L2 segments (hops), it is transferred by chain of routers, each one sets "source MAC" value to self address, "destination MAC" value to next router's MAC. So packet, received by server, has "source MAC" set to the last router's address unless client is in the same subnet.

Also JFYI MAC can be easily changed on PC to any chosen value.